# Photos storage on iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos

How do I know what photos have been downloaded to Photos on my iPhone? Does Apple continuously remove the copies from my local device after a period of time so that I don't run out of space? E.g., I have 80Gb iCloud storage taken up by Photos. I browse my photos through the iPhone Photos app and it downloads images that I linger on. I only have 12Gb space in total available on my iPhone, will I run out of space in the near future or are these downloads removed and reverted to thumbnails at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your iPhone will remove originals that you have not browsed recently, and then re-download them when you next look at them. If you want to learn more about it, lookup a [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)). With the new Photos app, the originals are stored in the cloud, and the images on your phone are just a cache. (Except that when you edit a photo in the cache, Apple preserves both the original and the edits in the cloud.)